# Allow run-time configuration of web service url using ATL soap and sproxy-generated proxy class

Tags: web-services, visual-c++

I have a Visual C++ application that communicates with an ASP.NET web service via ATL Soap.  The client application uses an sproxy-generated proxy class for the communication.  Looking at the generated proxy class, I noticed that the url for the web service is hard-coded in numerous places.

It would be preferable for the url to be configurable at run-time (e.g. stored in a config file).  Could anyone recommend a method for doing this?  It doesn't look like the class generated by sproxy is amenable to hand-editing.

Comment: If it really is hard-coded, i'd open a feature request issue at the ATL server project.

Comment: It turns out that the hard-coded URL is just the default.  Duh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hard-coded URL seen in the generated proxy code is just the default.  An alternate URL for the service can be specified at run-time by calling the SetUrl method on the proxy object.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    {
        TestService::CTestService ws;
        BSTR input = _bstr_t(_T("This is my input"));
        BSTR result;
        ws.SetUrl(_T("http://dummyUrl/dummyservice.asmx"));
        ws.Echo(input, &result);
    }
    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}
```